# King's Gambit, Wagenbach Defense 1.e4 e5 2.f4 exf4 3.Nf3 h5

Tags: opening, gambits, kings-gambit

Has this gambit (6.Ng5!) been played? (I only found games with 6.Ne5.) Is it any good? Is it the refutation of Black's silly 3...h5 (the [Wagenbach Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Gambit#Wagenbach_Defense:_3...h5))?

```
[FEN ""]

1.e4 e5 2.f4 exf4 3.Nf3 h5 4.d4 g5 5.h4 g4 6.Ng5 f6 7.Bxf4 fxg5 8.Bxg5 Be7 9.Qd2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my analysis, the line you give appears to be the best way White can play. After 9.Qd2, Stockfish 10 at depth 28 gives roughly +1. So I think it qualifies as a refutation of 3...h5.

I couldn't find any games where 6.Ng5 was played, but I did find a game that reached the same position on move 6 via transposition. The game was from 1788 (!) in the "London Casual Games" between two players named Cotter and Von Bruehl:

```
[White "Cotter"]
[Black "Von Bruehl"]
[Event "London Casual Games"]
[Date "1788"]

[fen ""]

1.e4 e5 2.f4 exf4 3.Nf3 g5 4.h4 g4 5.Ng5 h5 6.d4 {Transposing to the diagram you gave} f6 7.Bxf4 fxg5 8.hxg5 (8.Bxg5 {Is stronger, following your line}) d5 9.e5 Bf5 10.Bd3 Ne7 11.O-O Bg7 12.Bg3 Rf8 13.Bh4 Qd7 14.Nc3 a6 15.Qe2 Nbc6 16.Bf2 O-O-O 17.Na4 Bxd3 18.Qxd3 Nxe5 19.Qb3 b5 20.dxe5 bxa4 21.Qc3 d4 22.Qd3 Qb5 23.Qa3 Ng6 24.b3 Bxe5 25.bxa4 Qc6 26.Rab1 0-1.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this excellent answer! For a moment there I thought of calling it the Cotter Gambit, but not after Cotter's weak follow-up.

Comment: Is White's advantage smaller (according to the engine) if he simply plays the positionnal 4.h4 after 1.e4 e5 2.f4 ef4 3.Nf3 h5?

Comment: After you gave me the idea of looking for transpositions from the Allgaier Gambit, I found another one. (There shouldn't be very many, because after 1.e4 e5 2.f4 exf4 3.Nf3 g5 4.h4 g4 5.Ng5 h5 the normal move is 6.Bc4! not 6.d4.)

Comment: I found this in Colin Leach's booklet *KGA: Allgaier and Kieseritzky Gambits*. J. Weiss–von Gompers, Vienna 1906. 1.e4 e5 2.f4 exf4 3.Nf3 g5 4.h4 g4 5.Ng5 h5 6.d4 f6 7.Bxf4 fxg5 8.hxg5 d6 9.Nc3 Bg7 10.Qd2 Ne7 11.O-O-O Ng6 12.g3 Nc6 13.Bb5 Bd7 14.Bxc6 Bxc6 15.Rhe1 Qe7 16.Nd5 Qf7 17.c4 O-O-O 18.rf1 Qd7 19,Qa5 Kb8 20. c5 Bxd5 21.exd5 h4 22.Rd3 Qf5 23.Qxc7+ Kxc7 24.Bxd6+ Rxd6 25.cxd6+ Kxd6 26.Rxf6 h3 27.Rxf5 h3 28.Rf1 h2 29.Rh1 Bxd4 30.Rd3 Bf2 31.Kd1 Rh3 0-1

Comment: @bof interesting, so from what we've found it appears no one has ever played the stronger 8.Bxg5.

Comment: @Evargalo Actually after 4.h4 Stockfish says Black is at least equal since he has time to strike in the centre with 4...d5.

Comment: Please beware of using Stockfish evaluations for opening soundness! They are often quite volatile and dependent on how much time you run the engine itself!

Comment: @David I'm well aware of the limitations of Stockfish. For Stockfish 10 I've chosen a setting where the evaluations don't change dramatically depending on who's move it is. In addition, depth 28 is sufficient to get a general idea of a line's soundness, especially in the tactical position after 8.Bxg5. If I was building a serious repertoire I might let it think to depth 35-40.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance if you were building a serious repertoire you wouldn't be analyzing this line in the first place!

Comment: @David Not necessarily I might want to play the King's Gambit and need to know a proper refutation for 3...h5 :)